# Can an SWF be played in a player with play, pause, and drag bar at the bottom?  If not, 

Tags: video, flash

I've got an animating tool (Koolmoves) that produces SWF files as its output.  Is there a video player that allows one to play an SWF on the web with the same basic functions one sees on any video player, i.e. pause/stop/drag bar to control position of playback, etc?

If not (because of the way the SWF format works), can you please point me to the steps I need to do to make this possible, letting me know the converter you use/recommend, and also a player to use.  Please note I'm looking for just a very simple, "lightly skinned" player, just enough to give the user some control over the experience.  Total length of piece, in case that matters, is about 2 minutes.

Thanks much, Ray

Comment: I haven't heard of any player that does that, but it wouldn't be very hard to make one. The built-in functions, `play()`, `stop()`, and `gotoAndStop()` would make it a breeze.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
<a href="javascript:document.movie.Play()">Play</a>
<a href="javascript:document.movie.StopPlay()">Pause</a>
```

Reference including example:
[Pause Play SWF file using JavaScript](http://www.moosefishing.com/toc/courses/tutorials/web/java/pause_play_swf_file_using_javasc.htm)

Comment: Thanks Anne.  Any kind of drag bar possible with this, so that end-user can control where in the "movie" the content is played?  If not, is there a way to have buttons that have "section1", "section2", ...

Comment: ... other things would be how to easily restart the "movie", so they can see it again (without doing a reload on the page, ideally)

Comment: Use `gotoAndStop()` to reset the movie. Use `gotoAndPlay()` to start the movie at specific frames. Checkout [this](http://www.moock.org/webdesign/flash/fscommand/index.html#javascripttoflash) example including working [example](http://www.moock.org/webdesign/flash/fscommand/javascript-to-flash.html). In case you need a control bar I recommend to convert the `.swf` to `.flv` and use somethingting like Flowplayer or JW Player. There is currently no "simple way" to implement it yourself.

Comment: ...and why exactly would we need javascript to do this?

Comment: Do you have another suggestion? JavaScript is easy to implement. Plain HTML does not allow interaction like this (besides reloading the page to reset the movie). Embedding controls into the `.swf` is probably better, but Ray likes to use the `.swf` file created by  Koolmoves.

Comment: Thanks Anne.  Is there a way for me to know how many frames the SWF movie has (and then check how many seconds long the movie is, and use plain division to get close to the correct frame. Does that make sense.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: ... Anne -- I figured out a way to get this (roughly number of frames), so never mind.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Be carefull to correctly named the object: id="movie" and name attribute for movie must be to name="movie"

Answer (score 0):

This can be done loading external swf (eg. swf produced by koolmoves) inside another Flash Movie using ActionScript 3.0.

We need to create MovieClip Object to store the loaded swf reference. The typecast the loaded content of swf into a MovieClip and then add the reference for itself to control the timeline on entering every frame.

The full logic of it, is very well explained [here](http://www.parorrey.com/blog/flash-development/external-swf-player-with-play-pause-forward-rewind-buttons-and-seek-bar/comment-page-1/#comment-3284).

I hope it is of help, as the post seems quite old.